# Can we estimate the dimension of some function space?

Tags: dimension-theory-analysis

Can we estimate the dimension of some function space?

e.g. if $X$ is a locally compact Hausdorff space,

what is the (linear) dimension of $C(X)$(as a linear space), which represents the set of all continuous function on $X$?

what is the dimension of $C_{c}(X)$(as a linear space), , which denote the set of continuous, complex-valued functions on $X$ with compact support?

Or can we conclude that if  $X$ is a locally compact Hausdorff space, then 
$dimC_{c}(X) \geq 1$ ?

I'm more concerned about the second problem.
I need such conclusion "if $X$ is ...,then $dimC_{c}(X)>=1$, and there exist a non-zero linear functional on $C_{c}(X)$."

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Is it not enough to say when the dimensions are finite? In most cases the dimension of these spaces should be infinite, with finite discrete spaces being exceptions to this rule.

Comment: @neuguy: "In most cases the dimension of these spaces should be infinite?" which conditions?.I need such conclusion if X is ...,then dimCC(X)>=1,and there exist a non-zero linear functional on CC(X).

Comment: How about "if $X$ is nonempty," since if $X$ is paracompact Hausdorff then using Urysohn's lemma you can construct a nontrivial continuous function of compact support? And I think this extends easily to locally compact Hausdorff. Not sure about the non-zero linear functional part, though if $X$ is finite you'll get a finite-dimensional $C_c(X)$ and a dual of the same dimension.

Comment: @neuguy:How to use Urysohn's lemma? In which case can make dimCC(X)=+infinity?

Comment: A paracompact Hausdorff space is normal, so Urysohn's lemma applies. Use it on a singleton and the complement of the interior of a compact neighborhood (if a larger one exists) to get a nontrivial function of compact support. (I'm not being exact here, since I don't know the full answer either, but I think this might be a decent starting direction.)

Comment: @neuguy: You could write it out as an answer to some extent?